# How to return options based on data-attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have data-value attributes on all `<option>` in a `<select>` (see example below).

On page load I will have access to one of the values and I need to iterate through all the `<option>` values and find the `<option>` that I can use for further processing. We are attempting to do this with jQuery.

How would I iterate through the `<select>` to find the `<option>` with value in the data-value attribute?

```css
option {
  width: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selections" size="5">
<option data-value="1" value="a">A</option>
<option data-value="2" value="b">b</option>
<option data-value="3" value="c">c</option>
<option data-value="4" value="d">d</option>
<option data-value="5" value="e">e</option>
<option data-value="6" value="f">f</option>
<option data-value="7" value="g">g</option>
</section>
```

The goal is to take a data-value="5" and add data-selected="true" (see below)

```css
option {
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selections" size="5">
    <option data-value="1" value="a">A</option>
    <option data-value="2" value="b">b</option>
    <option data-value="3" value="c">c</option>
    <option data-value="4" value="d">d</option>
    <option data-value="5" value="e" data-selected="true">e</option>
    <option data-value="6" value="f">f</option>
    <option data-value="7" value="g">g</option>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.attr()` function to add data attribute to your option.

```
$(".selections").find("[data-value='5']").prop("selected", true).attr("data-selected", "true");
```

Working demo [here](https://codepen.io/khanhvdv/pen/yvyWOb)

Answer (score 0):

Use `[attribute]` selectors

```js
$(".selections").find("[data-value='5']").prop("selected", true).data("selected", "true");
```

```css
option {
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selections" size="5">
    <option data-value="1" value="a">A</option>
    <option data-value="2" value="b">b</option>
    <option data-value="3" value="c">c</option>
    <option data-value="4" value="d">d</option>
    <option data-value="5" value="e">e</option>
    <option data-value="6" value="f">f</option>
    <option data-value="7" value="g">g</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not set the data-selected attribute